# Trigger GitHub Action with just a URL and process url parameters

Tags: github, url, github-actions, github-api, url-parameters

Is it possible to trigger a GitHub action with just a URL and query the url parameters in the action?

I know that I can send an HTTP request to the GitHub API and trigge the repository_dispatch event, but this is not possible in my case because the device is not able to send an HTTP request. It can only "request" a URL and send the parameters in the URL. In the action I want to process the parameters and send a HTTP request to another endpoint. So I want to take the action only as an "in-between" point.

As an example I have this URL (which I made up for demonstration purposes):

`https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/blob/master/.github/workflows/test_action?param=hello`

Now I want to use the action to "listen" if a URL request arrives with certain parameters.

So is it possible to trigger a specific action in my repository with just a URL and use the parameters of the URL (in this case `param=hello`) in the action?

Comment: Can you not use [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) on that device?

Comment: Nope, I want to use it with my Fritz!Box and DynDNS. So I need a solution that I am only able to "request" a URL. Currently I have not yet managed that the update URL of the Fritz!Box points to my own network. If I could manage that it would be the ideal solution!

Comment: I also guess this could be something for the GitHub CLI. Have a look at the [workflow run](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run) command. There you can also input data via STDIN as JSON.

Comment: The Fritz!Box is not able to run these commands...

Comment: You can also use the Github API directly (through a `curl` command) to trigger a workflow. Creating a dispatch event or a repository dispatch event.

Comment: Like i said before. My device is not able to execute any terminal commands... It can only send a predefined URL request.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am gonna use Cloudflare Workers. It’s exactly what I need.